# Javascript .remove() function removes the first div but doesn't remove the other

Tags: javascript

I have this simple form where I am able to add input fields with a help of a button. There is also a button to delete an input field which are in a div. I used `.remove()` function (which I got from answers here in SO) which removes the first div but it doesn't remove the second one or the one's which I add with the help of `Add Field` button. Now there aren't any solution for this and this seems like a unique and weird problem. Can anybody help me with this? Here's the code:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const span = document.querySelector("span");
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#addField");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".delete-btn");
const urlDiv = document.querySelector(".url-pair");
const html = `
    <div class="url-pair">
        <input type="url" autofocus="true">
        <input type="number" value="50%">
        <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
`;

const deleteField = function(e) {
  urlDiv.remove();
}


addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  span.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", html);
});

deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteField);
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="urls-container">
    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="addField">Add Url</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const span = document.querySelector("span");
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#addField");

const html = `
        <div class="url-pair">
            <input type="url" autofocus="true">
            <input type="number" value="50%">
            <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
    `;


addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  span.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", html);
});

// listening click event on form element
form.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // target holds the specific HTMLElement which was clicked
  const target = e.target;

  // check if clicked element has class delete-btn, if no, stop
  if (!target.classList.contains('delete-btn')) return; // it was clicked outside the delete-btn

  // yes, the button was clicked 
  e.target.parentElement.remove(); // now remove its parent i.e div.url-pair from the DOM tree
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <div class="urls-container">
    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="addField">Add Url</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Hey, could you please explain what you did there? It works

Comment: He did a sort of *passive listening*: he listen for event on the parent and filter the actual target there

Comment: Look at the last 4 lines of JS code. try `console.log` at each line and even if you don't understand, ask me again and i will add some explanation later. Have fun :)

Comment: Hey please put up the explanation. Doesnt have to be detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the parent with class url-pair AND delegate

Here is the simplest script I could make you

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const container = document.querySelector(".urls-container");
  const html = container.querySelector(".url-pair").cloneNode(true); // wee need an empty copy
  document.getElementById("addField").addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.appendChild(html.cloneNode(true)); // take a copy
  });

  document.querySelector(".urls-container").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("delete-btn")) {
      tgt.closest("div.url-pair").remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.urls-container .url-pair:first-child .delete-btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="urls-container">
    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="addField">Add Url</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean the div with url-container?

Comment: No. The parent div of the button

Comment: Sorry mate. But can you please elaborate? If I remove the div with class url-pair, how can I target that div in my javascript as I want to remove the whole div?

Comment: Your button is added url-pair div. Is that not what you want to remove if delete is clicked?

Comment: The button 'Add Url` adds a div with class url-pair. And the button 'Delete' which is inside the div url-pair removes the div url-pair.

Comment: you missed the binding mistake

Comment: @Zak I believe my script is now the simplest. Note I do not insert HTML, but clone the first url-pair and hide the delete from all except the first

Answer (score 0):

Try with `e.target.parentElement.remove();`.

As your element is generated dynamically you need to [`delegate` event](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) handler.

Use event like below.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
  if (Array.from(event.target.classList).includes('delete-btn')) {
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

You can test output below.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const span = document.querySelector("span");
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#addField");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".delete-btn");
const urlDiv = document.querySelector(".url-pair");
const html = `
    <div class="url-pair">
        <input type="url" autofocus="true">
        <input type="number" value="50%">
        <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
`;

const deleteField = function(e) {
  urlDiv.remove();
}


addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  span.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", html);
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
  if (Array.from(event.target.classList).includes('delete-btn')) {
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="urls-container">
    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="addField">Add Url</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: you missed the binding mistake

Comment: @Greedo, yes, you are right. I have corrected the code. Thanks!!

Comment: `if (Array.from(event.target.classList).includes('delete-btn'))` can be written `if (event.target.classList.contains('delete-btn'))` like I did

Comment: @mplungjan, Thanks for suggestion. Initially I had thought to use `contains` but I had doubt that it will return `true` in case of element with class `delete-btn-1` similar to `string.contains`. But when you comment here I check for the documentation and I found it will work exactly as expected. `classList.contains` would be more `elegant` but I would go with `Array.from` just as an alternative of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the event only to the first button, and also, deleting only the first element.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const span = document.querySelector("span");
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#addField");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-btn");
const urlDiv = document.querySelector(".url-pair");
const html = `
    <div class="url-pair">
        <input type="url" autofocus="true">
        <input type="number" value="50%">
        <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
`;

const deleteField = function(e) {
  e.target.closest(".url-pair").remove();
}


addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  span.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", html);
  btnList = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-btn');
  btnList[btnList.length-1].addEventListener('click', deleteField);
});

Array.from(deleteBtn).forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', deleteField));
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="urls-container">
    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url">
      <input type="number">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url">
      <input type="number">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="addField">Add Url</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: it works with the ones already there. But if I add a new one with Add Url button then it doesn't work

Comment: @Zak now it does

Comment: This is highly inelegant to add an event listener for every delete element and then again when created. DRY.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const span = document.querySelector("span");
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#addField");
const deleteBtnList = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-btn");
const html = `
    <div class="url-pair">
        <input type="url" autofocus="true">
        <input type="number" value="50%">
        <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
`;

const deleteField = function(e) {
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
}


addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  span.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", html);
});

Array.from(deleteBtnList).forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('click', deleteField);
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="urls-container">
    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" autofocus="true">
      <input type="number" value="50%">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="addField">Add Url</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: it works with the ones already there. But if I add a new one with Add Url button then it doesn't work